# Similar results for Bernstein's Inequality for Dependent Matrices

Tags: probability, inequality, reference-request

I am looking for resources (the answer does not necessarily to be concrete inequalities, the links of resources are also welcome) for the Matrix Bernstein's Inequalities for (weakly) dependent matrices.

The theorem 1.6.2 and 1.6.3 in [this literature](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0792.pdf) suggested some spectral norm upper bounds for concentration inequalities for the matrices. But they assumed that the matrices are independent.

Also, the [Wikipedia page of Bernstein's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)#Some_of_the_inequalities) has some result of the Bernstein's inequality for weakly dependent variables, but they are scalar.

My question is, is there any inequalities for the Bernstein's inequality for weakly dependent matrix, as 1.6.3 in [this literature](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0792.pdf)? Specifically:

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k\dots$ be vectors, such that $||x_i||<L$ and also $\mathbb{E}(x_i|x_{i-1})=0$. Also we let $A=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}(x_ix_i^T)$. Then what can we say about $\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T-A$?

I have tried to look for resources (in Google Scholar and arXiv, as well as the citations of the Wikipedia), but I can't find something I really want... Is there any more information for the distribution needed to answer this question?

Many thanks for any kind of help!